# How to apply Back button pressed in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I am new on android. I cant handle onBackPressed method. I have an Activity class which has four fragment like A,B,C, D. When i lunched Activity by default Fragment A is active and there are link on fragment A to move another Fragment. I want when move another Fragment like B,C,D from Fragment A and pressed Back button it return to Fragment A and if i pressed Back button from Fragment A it show a dialog box.
I used onBackPressed() like below

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

    // set dialog message
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

But it work on all fragment  and i want to work only Fragment A

Comment: Do you have a way to tell when Fragment A is the one shown?

Comment: yes when Fragment A is one Shown

Comment: Check my answer and let me know you overcome or not

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle such requirements in the Activity's onBackPressed only. I usually follow the following approach:

I keep an enum having all the fragments defined and a parameter to track the current fragment:

```
enum FRAGMENTS{
    fragmentA, fragmentB, fragmentC, fragmentD
}
FRAGMENTS mCurrentFragment;
```

Now the logic where you change the fragment should have:

```
public void changeFragment(FRAGMENTS newFragment){
    //Your logic
    mCurrentFragment = newFragment;
}
```

And finally the logic onBackPressed:

```
onBackPressed{
     if(mCurrentFragment == FRAGMENTS.fragmentA){
          //Your code here of asking the user if he/she really wants to quit
          super.onBackPressed();
     }else{
          changeFragment(getPreviousFragment(mCurrentFragment));
     }
}
```

If you dont want to use enum, you can have final int or any other string values to represent different fragments and a mCurrentFragment parameter to keep a track of the currentFragment being shown and then you can easily play with the code in your Activity's onBackPressed method

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Add fragment to `backStack` while replacing

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

And then override `onBackPressed` method inside an Activity

Answer (score 1):

So Here is your answer which you are looking for :)

### Method 1

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        // Your stuff here
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        // set dialog message
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity

                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();

    }


}
```

//Tell me if you face any issue

### Method 2

or in your case just paste this method in your main activity so you can also achieve it what you want :)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

    // set dialog message
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity

                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Do you really think your answer would solve Shailesh problem because he wants an alert only and only when fragment A is showing not other and your code would create an alert on all fragments.

Comment: Yes in that case method 1 would be work well for shailesh and method 2 works for all fragments back button to be track but mothod 2 also preferable if we pass some conditions on it when backbutton is track

Comment: Method 1 wont work for him either i guess. because on clicking back button on any fragment would make the if condition true always for KEYCODE_BACK.

Comment: Nope it will work if he put method1 inside FragmentA because method1 we can put in any particular fragment and we can track that particular fragment's click.

Comment: You cant override `onKeyDown` method in `Fragment`. Do you know that? You can override in your `Activity` only, which is like `onBackPressed` method which you cant override in `Fragment`

Comment: @Clairvoyant i know it that's why i have mentioned in method 2 that if you want to use that code paste it on mainactivity so he also able to track entire app's backpressed

Comment: @KishanSoni thank sir.method 2 woking fine for  me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the onBack pressed method then add this code in your in onActivityCreated() method

```
getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                      getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code hope it helps.

```
//Always replace/add your fragment with a tag so that you can use that tag in future

     Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Name");//Fragment Name is a tag to identify fragment
     if (fr == null) {
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
     .replace(R.id.frame_container, new Demo_Fragment(), "Fragment_Name").commit();
     }

    //Now override onBackPressed method in MainActivity Only no need to do it in Fragment Class
    @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
     Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentA");
    if(fr==null)
    //replace FragmentA
    else
    //Show Alert Box
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to do following

Create method on the BaseFragment or Activity that save the current fragment object

```
 public void setCurrentFragment(Fragment currentFragment) {
                this.currentFragment = currentFragment;
               }
```

and also create a method that return your current fragment object

```
public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
        return currentFragment;
    }
```

now just you need to call the `getCurrentFragment` Method and checked that if the Fragment is an instance of the A fragment or not

```
if (getCurrentFragment() instanceof AFragment) {
            showAlert
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
```